# How can I fix my loop to stop when i enter number less than 1 and greater than 50 and to stop when more than 20 inputs?

Tags: java, arrays

I need the code to stop if the user enters a number less than 1 or greater than 50. I have written what is below so far. The loop also goes in an infinite loop and I need it to stop after 20 inputs. Any suggestions?

```
KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
Ex4Method object = new Ex4Method();
int occurences [] = new int [51];
int [] nums = new int[20];
int i=0;
System.out.println("Enter a number (1-50): ");
nums[i] = reader.readInt();
while(nums[i]>= 1 && nums[i]<=50)
{
    while(i<19) 
    {
        
        System.out.print("Enter a number (1-50): ");
        nums[i] = reader.readInt();
        
    
    }
```

Comment: You are not incrementing `i` after every input. Increment `i` so that it can exit when `if (i<19)` becomes false. Use `for loop` instead, it is much better and easier to read than this nested loops.
Like,

`
for(int i=0;i<20;++i){
  nums[i] = reader.readInt();
  if(nums[i]<1 || nums[i]>50) break;
}
`

Comment: @vicki, so should I just replace the while with if and do i++ after every input?

Comment: If you are using an IDE, then it should have a debugger. You should learn how to use it in order to debug your programs. Then you would see that the value of `i` does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `while(nums[i]>= 1 && nums[i]<=50)` with `while(nums[i]>= 1 && nums[i]<=50 && i<19)`, put `i++` inside the loop and remove the `while(i<19)` loop.

Sample:

```
KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
Ex4Method object = new Ex4Method();
int occurences [] = new int [51];
int [] nums = new int[20];
int i=0;
System.out.println("Enter a number (1-50): ");
nums[i] = reader.readInt();
while(nums[i]>= 1 && nums[i]<=50 && i<19)
{
    i++;
    System.out.print("Enter a number (1-50): ");
    nums[i] = reader.readInt();
}
```

Comment: @NavoShankar, I have updated the answer and put an example.

Comment: I would also suggest that you could do some research and you will figure out how to not repeat the "System.out.println("Enter a number (1-50): "); nums[i] = reader.readInt();" using "do / while".

Answer (score 1):

you can code like this .

```
while(nums[i]>= 1&&nums[i]<50&&i<20)
{
     i++;
    System.out.print("Enter a number (1-50): ");
    nums[i] = reader.readInt();

}
```

Comment: yea so i have done that but once i enter the second number the loop stops.